# Highlight cells in output Excel file

Tags: r, colors, readxl

I have a data frame `Data2015` like this :

```
> head(Data2015)
    Sample.id Locality.Name Chemicals Activity.Value Measuring.Unit Uncertainty.Value  Uncertainty.Unit
1 104/22/4/P3    xxxxxxxx     CO2         0.192         g/L             0.122              g/L   
2 104/22/4/P3    xxxxxx       C0          1060         mg/L             1060              mg/L    
3 104/22/4/P3    xxxxxx       nh3         0.765         g/L             0.061              g/L   
4 104/22/4/P3    xxxxx        O3          0.876         g/L             0.061              g/L
5  2-0434a F1    xxxxxxx      Co2         0.145         g/L             0.061              g/L
6  2-0434a F1    xxxxxxx      CO          1654         mg/L             9876              mg/L
```

I manipulate the data like so:

```r
library("dplyr")
Data2015 <- Data2015 %>% mutate(Chemicals = toupper(Chemicals)) 

Data2015$Activity.Value <- ifelse(Data2015$Measuring.Unit == "mg/L",Data2015$Activity.Value * 0.001,Data2015$Activity.Value)
Data2015$Uncertainty.Value <- ifelse(Data2015$Uncertainty.Unit == "mg/L",Data2015$Uncertainty.Value * 0.001,Data2015$Uncertainty.Value)
Data2015$Measuring.Unit[Data2015$Measuring.Unit == 'mg/L'] <- 'g/L'
Data2015$Uncertainty.Unit[Data2015$Uncertainty.Unit == 'mg/L'] <- 'g/L'
```

And write the final data frame as Excel workbook:

```r
wb1 = createWorkbook()
sheet1 = createSheet(wb1, "Data2015")
cs1 <- CellStyle(wb1) + Font(wb1, isBold=TRUE)

addDataFrame(Data2015, sheet=sheet1, startColumn=1, row.names=F)
saveWorkbook(wb1, "Data2015_corrected.xlsx")
```

Is it possible to color (in green) the cases in the output where the values  have been changed?

Comment: What do you mean by "color in green"? You want to highlight the changes in the command line output? IMHO it is not useful nor effective to try to do anything like this but some king of highlighting can be probably implemented by creating special object class and associated print method. Easier solution would be to create new column where you can store a TRUE/FALSE indicator if any of the cells in a row was changed and filter based on this column...

Comment: First, thank you for your help. By "color in green", I mean, when I will be exporting my df (>20 000 rows) in a new .xlsx file named "Data2015_corrected.xlsx", my colleagues would like to directly see if any the cells was converted (when comparing with the initial .xlsx file named "Data2015.xlsx"). How would you implement it with your new new column TRUE/FALSE ?

Comment: Well then just create the column I suggested and use conditional highlighting in Excel itself, I am not aware of any packages that would do that directly from R.

Comment: But how do you automatically fill in the new column with "TRUE" or "FALSE", depending on whether the cells of a row will be changed. I think that about 11000 (out of > 20000 rows in my df) will be changed

Comment: That is a different question, I edited this one to be clearly asking about the options of coloring. One option would be using the same if/else construct as you used already...